# Different ways of declaring Linked List Nodes in C#

Tags: c#

I am a new programmer to C#. I am trying to create a simple linked list as practice. What are the differences when you declare:

```
Node newNode = new Node();

Node newNode = new Node;

Node newNode;
```

I see these declarations all over the place, but what are the differences?
Also, I used to program in C++, and the use of pointers are crucial in creating LinkedLists. However, I've heard that you almost never use pointers in C#; how does that work then?

Thanks

Comment: `Node newNode = new Node;` is not valid C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Node newNode = new Node();
```

Will declare space for a reference to a Node, and assign a newly constructed node to it.

```
Node newNode = new Node;
```

Is not valid C#, as C# requires either the () or an assignment list { }

```
Node newNode;
```

Will declare space for a reference to a Node, and leave that space unassigned. You will get errors if you try to use it before it is assigned. If you want it to not refer to any instance of Node, assign null to it.

Pointers are not commonly used in C#, but all references to any object declared as a class are essentially the same thing as pointers. Object types declared as struct are almost never pointed to, they are copied whenever assigned, while object types declared as class are always pointed to and only copied if you do so explicitly by creating a new instance.

Essentially, where in C++ the declaration of the variable determines if it is a pointer, depending on whether you use the *, in C# the type of storage is determined when the object type is declared. You can for most purposes treat anything declared as a class as a pointer, and anything declared as a struct as "on-the-stack".

Comment: I would add that this fact about class and struct is why you can assign null to any type declared as a class, but you cannot assign null to any type declared as a struct.

Comment: Oh, and I'm also assuming that Node is declared as a class, since I speak of assigning null to it. Since you are building a linked list, you will need your node to be declared as a class so you can assign null where the list ends.

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick feedback, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
// declares newNode as a reference to a newly instantiated instance of the Node() class
Node newNode = new Node();

// not valid syntax....
Node newNode = new Node;

// Declares newNode as a reference to a Node() object that doesn't 'point' anywhere, 
// i.e. it's unassigned
Node newNode;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Node newNode = new Node();` will create a new `Node` instance and store a reference to it on `newNode`.

`Node newNode;` will only declare a variable but will not be initialized, you can think about it like a C++ uninitialized pointer.

And finally, `Node newNode = new Node;` isn't even valid C#, it will not compile.